# How to implements redis pipeline similar behavior in aerospike

Tags: java, aerospike

Can any one please suggest, how to implement/use redis pipeline like behavior in aerospike java client.

Comment: I have not used redis extensively, so not sure if I will be able to answer your question to the point, but as far as I know the difference between Redis and Aerospike is that Aerospike is multi-threaded from the go. Plus Aerospike has a Java client library that is a extra intelligent layer between your code and Aerospike server. So in any case you may not have to worry about pipelining anything in Aerospike. You can use it assuming your commands are pipelined and you should get the response. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis is a single-threaded database with a simple request/response protocol. Since every command must be processed one by one, and each request has to have a response back, this can add up to a lot of latency if you have many operations. Pipelining is a way to send multiple commands at once, have the server process all of them, then get all the results back in a batch.

Aerospike is multi-threaded with its own custom wire protocol that can run multiple commands in parallel over the same connection. The official drivers handle sending commands as efficiently as possible.

Aerospike does have something called Multiple Operations which means you can send multiple commands that *act on the same key* as one combined command. The java (and other language) drivers also support async operations which should further increase concurrent performance in your code.

Comment: Aerospike also has the ability to do batch-reads to get multiple records concurrently.

Comment: > run multiple commands in parallel over the same connection  --- Curious how is this achieved.

Comment: @BaiyanHuang Almost all wire protocols achieve this the same way, by using an abstraction on top of the underlying TCP connection to create command streams and/or add identifiers to requests and responses so that both client and server can process them concurrently. Redis protocol doesn't have this abstraction and is just a simple TCP server with text-based request/response.